# Angular-material. Autocomplete directive

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material

I have some problem with autocomplete. And my question is: Can I send my own personally typed text instead object from autocomplete list?

When I send object from list to "person.eamil" it's ok, but
when I send normal text to "person.email" I get null instead my text.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<md-autocomplete
  ng-model="person.email"
  ng-disabled="false"
  md-no-cache="true"
  md-selected-item="person.email"
  md-search-text-change="setPersonValidEmail(person, !innerForm.email.$error.email);"
  md-search-text="searchText"
  md-items="item in people"
  md-item-text="item.email"
  md-min-length="0"
  placeholder="some@one.com"
  ng-click="addOurPersonIfNecessary($index);"
  name = "email">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.name}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Try to use another autocomplete plugin like this:

https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

Answer (score 0):

Md-selected-item here is expecting an object that is populated in people. Only then it can populate the auto complete. You can pass the text to md-search-text

Comment: So how i can pass data from input to md-search-text object? Sorry for this stupid question but I am new in angular.

Comment: I try to use focuseout() / focusein() but didn't work.

Comment: focusin and focuout are overridden in angular autocomplete behaviour, to close and open the autocomplete box hence using it wont help